# insert batch option in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I can use insert batch in codeigniter but my problem is if I have 7 field in my form and i fill up 5 field in the form and submit I get 7 row in db. 5 row is ok but others 2row show sl no, date and invoice no. I want only 5 data which is fill up by form not others. my model is

```
public function purchase(){  
  $data = array(
    array(
     'date'=> $this->input->post('date'),
     'vendor_name'=>$this->input->post('vendor_name'),
     'model'=>$this->input->post('model'),
     'price' =>$this->input->post('price'), 
     'purchase_quantity'=>$this->input->post('quantity'),
     'amount'  =>$this->input->post('price')*$this->input->post('quantity'),
     'invoice_no'=>$this->input->post('invoice')
     ),
      array(
     'date'=> $this->input->post('date'),
     'vendor_name'=>$this->input->post('vendor_name2'),
     'model'=>$this->input->post('model2'),
     'price' =>$this->input->post('price2'), 
     'purchase_quantity'=>$this->input->post('quantity2'),
     'amount'  =>$this->input->post('price2')*$this->input->post('quantity2'),
     'invoice_no'=>$this->input->post('invoice')
     ),

      array(
     'date'=> $this->input->post('date'),
     'vendor_name'=>$this->input->post('vendor_name3'),
     'model'=>$this->input->post('model3'),
     'price' =>$this->input->post('price3'), 
     'purchase_quantity'=>$this->input->post('quantity3'),
    'amount'  =>$this->input->post('price3')*$this->input->post('quantity3'),
     'invoice_no'=>$this->input->post('invoice')
     )
     );
    $insert = $this->db->insert_batch('purchase',$data);
   return $insert; 
  }
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple insert query on foreach

```
foreach ($data as $row){
$insert = $this->db->insert('purchase',$row);
```

Comment: could you show me the results 
price
foreach ($data as $row){
print_r( $row['price']);
exit;
}

Comment: 45  bmbmbm  18-09-2014  mizan  cc32  900  5  4500
46  bmbmbm  18-09-2014    0   0
47  bmbmbm  18-09-2014   0  0   0

Comment: are you sure you are just  print_r( $row['price']); exit

Comment: 45=sl bmbmbm=invoice 18-09-2014=date mizan=vendor cc32=model 900=price 5=quantity 4500= amount

Comment: it should only return your price

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61532/discussion-on-answer-by-ijaz-ahmed-bhatti-insert-batch-option-in-codeigniter).